# How do I properly set up Latex-suite in Gvim?

Tags: miktex, vim, vim-latex

I just installed Miktex, and downloaded Latex Suite latest snapshot.

I extracted its files in both **C:\Program files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles** and **C:\Program files (x86)\Vim\vim74** *(I'm not sure why I have these two directories; it may be due to I have gVim and vim from cygwin)*.

I also edited my _vimrc to add the options that Latex-Suite installation guide says.

It seems to work, since commands like !latex and !yap example.tex are executed for a simple tex file. However, in gVim the menu tabs related to Tex do not appear. Also, the command "echo Tex_CompileRule_dvi" tells this is an undefined variable.

I'm afraid I might be missing some things attrying to use Latex within gVim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vim-latex installation instructions](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download) say to put the files into `~/vimfiles` if you are running on Windows. Neither of the paths you mentioned above seem like they would be `~/vimfiles`.

My interpretation of those directions would be to put the files into a `vimfiles` directory in your windows home directory - same place that your `_vimrc` file would be.

Comment: Many thanks! I have two partitions and it was installed in the second one which I did not intend to use for installing programs. "echo $HOME" told me the correct location and now it is properly working.